# Magento : CMS upload image fail silently

Tags: magento, file-upload, content-management-system, tinymce

I am trying to figure out why the tinyMCE WYSIWYG editor in the CMS module of Magento will not upload images. I can create/delete folders but any file will simply not get uploaded, and there seems to be no message as to why the file is not successfully written on the server.

Anyone may have an idea why?

#### ** Update **

I'm using Magento 1.6.2. I have tried to track down the problem and it *seems* that the controller never gets executed. I have added a line to log the arguments in the `uploadAction()` action (in `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_ImagesController`) and nothing gets logged.

This is project inherited from someone else, and was modified to some extend, but nothing seems to point out that this part of Magento would have been touched in anyway by the modifications.

#### ** EDIT**

The project associated with this question has been dropped and I no longer can provide an answer to this question. If anyone can confirm a working answer (as this problem was apparantly common with Magento), I will gladly mark that answer as "accepted".

Otherwise, I will flag this question for removal for the aformentioned reasons.

Thank you.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Is your server using `Suhosin` and/or `mod_security` by chance?

Comment: Other than that, have you already tried downgrading the prototype js library to 1.6.1? Iirc, there was something buggy causing image uploads to fail.

Comment: About `prototype.js`, it's 1.7 and I see that there's 1.6.0.2 sitting there (named `prototype_old.js`) which leads me to think that the previous guy needed 1.7... for some reason. Would you happen to know exactly what cause uploads to fail? I'll try to Google about that and see if this could be it.

Comment: No, not exactly, I'm sorry. Never really had a deep look into this. Iirc, it got something to do with prototype 1.7 changing their JSON implementation to be EcmaScript 5 compliant, but I wouldn't go out on a limb for that.

Comment: Do you see existing images in the folder?

Answer (score 14):

Other than solutions provided here, it may occur when you use a CDN (*or a different domain*) for your javascript and media files in admin panel. If you use CDN, use it for your **website(s) scope** and use your own domain for **default scope**. It will make your website(s) media and javascript files to be loaded from CDN, and backend's media and javascript files to be loaded from your own domain. This will solve your problem.

Comment: If you use a subdomain, you can also enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) to make your javascripts work with your domain. Google for "CORS enabling", it differs what type of system you use.

Answer (score 5):

There are some known issues with flash image uploader on Magento. Unfortunately when it falls, it falls silently. Here are some cases when smth can break it:

1. if you try to use it with secured connection using open ssl certificate
2. if you're using it on server with apache authentication
3. on some Magento versions with prototype 1.7

I think the latter is your best bet. Maybe you should try to apply the patch from here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4348/P45/#t327010

Comment: I can only upvote your answer for now as I have not heard from my client (never got the "good to fix" go from him) about this. But I'm sure it has something to do with Prototype. The original programmer did upgrade some things with that Magento installation and I bet he's responsible of breaking stuff :) Thansk for the link to the patch.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a cross domain problem, and one quite hard to find if you ask me...

What was puzzling me was that the uploader for product images was working like a charm but the one in the CMS section was failing completely silently. We are serving the skin folder from an Amazon S3 bucket, and the flash uploader lives under that folder.

Interestingly enough, our version of Magento (1.7.0.2) is using two different methods to calculate the path to the SWF file, depending whether you are under CMS or Product update.

The CMS file (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml) is using the following method to embed the Flash Uploader:

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('media/uploader.swf') ?>
```

While the Product image uploader is using:

```
<?php echo $this->getUploaderUrl('media/uploader.swf') ?>
```

In our case, the first one resolves to the AWS S3 url, obviously in a separate domain, while the second one will still reference the local domain's url.

So yeah, the quick, dirty fix would be to replace getSkinUrl for getUploaderUrl in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml. Alternatively you can extend the core to load a different template in which you would have replaced that method.

I hope this helps somebody... I wish I had found something like this five days ago when I first stumbled upon the issue :-)

Comment: Had the same problem. +1 for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using flash uploader with https? If so, is your secure address in differente domain (usually used in shareds ssl)?
I got some trouble with this. I solved by installing a flash uploader disabler plugin.

You can download the plugin with this downloader key:

> http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Dull_Uploader

I hope it helps.